# increment variable for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following data:

```
ID    Time
1     01-01-01
1     02-01-01
1     02-01-01
2     01-01-01
```

I would like to start with 0 and increase one by one for each new time by group ID. SO I need to get something like that

```
ID    Time       Result
1     01-01-01   0
1     02-01-01   1
1     02-01-01   1
2     01-01-01   0
```

Is there a smart way to do it shortly? (Note that this is just for illustration, real data is large enough.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `pd.factorize`:

```
df['Result'] = df.groupby('ID')['Time'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
df
```

Output:

```
   ID      Time  Result
0   1  01-01-01       0
1   1  02-01-01       1
2   1  02-01-01       1
3   2  01-01-01       0
```

Answer (score 3):

[Rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) can be used here with one caveat that it starts rank from 1. Handle it by subtracting 1.

```
df['Result'] = df.groupby('ID').Time.rank('min').astype(int) - 1

    ID  Time        Rank
0   1   2001-01-01  0
1   1   2001-02-01  1
2   1   2001-02-01  1
3   2   2001-01-01  0
```

Comment: This is another really smart way of doing it.  +1